# 'setOnItemClickListener/setOnItemLongClickListener' not working after adding 'HorizontalScrollView' to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I have the Listeners working just fine for my 'standard' listview, but I wanted to make the individual listview items horizontally scrollable, which took a lot of trial&error, but it finally worked. However, that cost me sensitivity in listening to any click. I hope there's a simple fix, like adding another attribute etc.

Here is my listener (minimized):

```html
        listViewAllCards.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

                Log.i("LOG: (DP) SHORT","position " + position + " ID: " + id);

                switch (position) {

                // Training
                case 0:
                break;
              }
            }
        });
```

and this is my xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/database_page_list_selector"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnailDatabase"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="KNOW"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/databaseListViewKnowLevel" />

            <TextView
                android:text="SLEEP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/databaseListViewSleepLevel" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtlvDictionaryLookUpForeignWord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/databaseListViewKnowLevel"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:text="CHAR"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/databaseListViewForeignAlt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtlvDictionaryLookUpForeignWord"
                android:text="ALT"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/databaseListViewForeignWord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/databaseListViewForeignAlt"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="WORD"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/databaseListViewEnglishWord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ENGLISH"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtlvDictionaryLookUpForeignWord"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtlvDictionaryLookUpForeignWord" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[EDIT] Interesting, when I click the horizontal scroll area, it works, so it might be an issue with the scroll stealing the 'focus' from the the listview item:

[image]

[EDIT] I added the following to the class code, the OnItem listener is still in the 'onCreate' snippet (which I hope is fine). I see this firing, but still no sensitivity on the actual item:

```html
    private class CustomAllCardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flashcard> {

        public CustomAllCardsAdapter() {

            super(DatabasePage.this, R.layout.database_page_horizontal_list_view_item,allFlashcards);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;

            if (itemView == null) {

                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.database_page_horizontal_list_view_item, parent, false);
            }

            final HorizontalScrollView hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hScrollView);
            hScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    Log.i("DP: DEBUG", "HSCROLL" + event);

                    hScrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the parent layout of your list item..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"   //add this
            android:background="@drawable/database_page_list_selector"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">
```

**EDIT**

add `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` for the `scrollview` touch event

```
scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
scrollView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        scrollView1.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: sadly, it didn't help, still no reaction. To make sure, I removed the HorizontalScroll again and it works. Any other ideas ?

Comment: probably showing my ignorance, but it took a while to avoid the null-pointer since I wasn't sure where to put the snippet. Ended up putting it inside the ArrayAdapters 'getView'. I see it being executed (via Log.i), but the onClick still doesn't fire. I kept the line in the xml (since it seems to at least make the scroller sensitivie'. So your snippet is attempting to set a listener on the scroll only to disable it later, right ?